# Use jQuery on Elements from .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-load

Is it possible to use jQuery on elements inserted into the page using:

```
jQuery('#here').load('slick.txt');
```

I want to use jQuery on one of the elements in slick.txt but it doesn't work:

```
jQuery('p').hide();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a **Load complete** [callback](https://api.jquery.com/load/) to `.load()`

> A callback function that is executed when the request completes.

```
jQuery('#here').load('slick.txt', function() {
    jQuery('p').hide();
});
```